# How to extract pairs of attributes from an HTML document using XPath?

Tags: php, dom, xpath, attributes

The given HTML document contain a form like this:

```
<form>
    <div controlType="yyy1" xmlTag="zzz1">...</div>
    <div controlType="yyy2" xmlTag="zzz2">...</div>
</form>
```

I need collect this data:

```
$div[0]      = array('yyy1', 'zzz1');
$div[1]      = array('yyy2', 'zzz2');
```

The required pairs of attributes are `controlType` and `xmlTag` for each `div` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Evaluate these two XPath expressions**:

```
/form/div[$k]/@controlType
```

and:

```
/form/div[$k]/@xmlTag
```

to populate `$div[$k -1]`

where `$k` must be substituted with the numbers, 1, 2, ..., `count(/form/div)`

One could be tempted to combine the two expressions above into a single XPath expression:

```
/form/div[$k]/@*
```

however an implementation of XPath is allowed to return the attributes in any order (XPath doesn't define ordering amongst attributes) and it wouldn't be clear which of the two attributes comes first in the selected nodes, and which comes second.

Answer (score 0):

**my two cents if it helps**

```
            var doc = '<form xmltag="xxx"><div controltype="yyy1" xmltag="zzz1">...</div><div controltype="yyy2" xmltag="zzz2">...</div></form>';

        var result = [];

        $(doc).children().each(function () {
            var ctrl = $(this);
            if (ctrl.is('div')) {
                result.push([ctrl.attr('controlType'), ctrl.attr('xmlTag')]);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you serious? I ask for a php based solution, not javascript! Any way looks nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
@$url = "http://XXX.xom"
$path     = "//div[@class='sb_tlst']//a";
$contents = get_contents($url, $path);
foreach ($contents as $value) 
{ 
    /* do something */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My final solution based in the excellent idea proposal by @dimitre-novatchev:

```
$res             = $xpath->query("//form//div/@xmltag"); // OBS: xmltag not xmlTag
$total_fields    = $res->length;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_fields; $i ++ )
{
    $r       = $xpath->query("//form//div[$i]/@xmltag");
    $xmltag  = $r->item(0)->value;

    $r           = $xpath->query("//form//div[$i]/@controltype");
    $controltype = $r->item(0)->value;

    $div[$i - 1] = array(
        'xmltag'         => $xmltag,
        'controltype'    => $controltype
    );
}
```

Output sample:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'xmltag' => 'Case_Number',
    'controltype' => '',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'xmltag' => 'Plaintiff',
    'controltype' => 'RadioButtons',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'xmltag' => 'Plaintiff_Name',
    'controltype' => '',
  ),
```

Beautiful!